# ant and maven not working in jenkins slave

Tags: maven, jenkins, ant

I have ant build script with maven stuff inside . I run ant from my local machine and it works fine. But, When i run it from jenkins slave, it can only run ant stuff and then complains about ***mvn.cmd command not found.*** . I have ant and maven mentioned in global tools configuration in jenkins because of which it installs ant and runs build.xml but inside build.xml, it encounters mvn.cmd and fails.

What can I do here to resolve this? I have been trying to get this working for many weeks now but no sucess.

Comment: You put Maven on your PATH?

Comment: no . maven has to run on a random slave which gets provisioned

Comment: So, are you sure your Ant script does not expect that Maven is on the Path?

Comment: it expects maven in the path. but since it is a random slave, i cannot install anyting beforehand and want that it installs maven just like it installed ant.